# dotnet tool install -g unable to resolve

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have the .NET 5 SDK installed, but I do not have Visual Studio installed.

Whenever I tried to perform a tool installation, example `dotnet tool install -g csharprepl`, it always results in:

```
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'csharprepl (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'csharprepl (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net5.0/any'.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'csharprepl' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.
```

How do I use `dotnet tool install` in the absence of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem from a fresh install of win10/.netcore (without Visual Studio) - it seems that the default `NuGet.config` doesn't have the package sources setup by default (at least for me).

To resolve this, I added the following `packageSource` config at `%AppData%\NuGet\`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**Edit**: Additionally, you may need to download `NuGet.exe` to a tools folder, and add this to your `PATH` to use nuget.

Comment: Yes, I need to first download NuGet.exe. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue with a fresh install of dotnet 6.0 SDK with VS Code installed. I did not have to separately install NuGet, but the NuGet.config file had no package sources. Adding the packageSource config listed here fixed me up.

Comment: Perfect, I added this to `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` and it worked! Thanks!